# Chrome forcing sidebar down on slow website

Tags: css, performance, google-chrome, webkit

I have developed a website: http://dannalab.com which *was* working fine. But now in Chrome the sidebar is pushed further down the page?

Client is also claiming the website takes extremely long to load because of the Google Web Font being used - seems extremely odd to me, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The sidebar appears to start at the end of the page text, which is default behavior. Have you tried using `float: left`?

Comment: @nosuchthingasstars There is nothing called `display: float;`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I know, that was edited; see new comment.

Comment: The webfont takes me around 40ms to download, so think it must just be them! You could always either get them to install Lato locally, or embed the font yourself rather than relying on Google, perhaps their office has a proxy or something.

Comment: -1 and a vote to close, because when you fix the issue on your site, the question will be useless to others.  Please include the relevant code.

Comment: You keep changing your accepted answers huh? Funny!

Comment: It was a mix of the two!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float: left;` to `.side` in your CSS

Answer (score 1):

#### Found the issue here. Please *update* the *CSS*:

```
.side {
    padding: 25px 0 25px 10px;
}
```

And yeah, giving a `float: left;` above too works.

#### Explanation

The padding on the both sides are more than the left side width given. So, it is breaking and coming down. If you reduce the padding, it would fix the issue.

#### FYI: `style.css` **`Line: 236`**

#### Screenshot:

[image: Chrome Preview]

Comment: Please explain why this is the answer.

Comment: @tomaroo What isn't working? How did you check?

Comment: I asked you for a detailed explanation, not for me, but for the quality of this whole page. Since when the OP fixes his page (the link becomes meaningless; no code, get it?), no future reader would have any clue what the original issue was, or how your answer could have solved it.

Comment: @Sparky672 Is the given explanation fine or not?

Comment: Yes, it's certainly a lot better than it was.

Comment: It kind of worked, had to mess around with sizes and float however